# When i select a radio button value i need to display and hide some of the controls... this is my code below and it is not working

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "yes")
    {
        TextBox1.Visible = true;
        FileUpload1.Visible = true;
        Image1.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        TextBox1.Visible = true;
        FileUpload1.Visible = false;
        Image1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

This is my c# code. i have added OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" this is my asp.net code...  please help me with error!

Here is the important part of my `.aspx` page:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1"
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">    
      <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Yes</asp:ListItem> 
      <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>    
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: what about it is not working?

Comment: what is the error message you are receiving?

Comment: there is no error! its just that the code isnt working

Comment: what is the code supposed to be doing that it is not doing? is the event not firing?

Comment: ya the event isnt working

Comment: if the radio button value is yes then text box, image and file upload had to be displayed and if the radio button value is no then only textbox has to be displayed

Comment: in your answer, can you include the code from your `.aspx` page that has your drop down list?

Comment: <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged"  runat="server"         
        style="z-index: 1; left: 315px; top: 345px; position: absolute; height: 52px; width: 84px"       >
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your **RadioButtonList1**'s **autopost back property true** ! in .aspx page and check....

Comment: you should upvote his answer and mark it as the solution then :)

Comment: @user3526930  your welcome ! please mark as a answer !

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the autopostback of the RadioButtonList  is  not set .

The AutoPostBack property is used to set or return whether or not an automatic post back occurs when the user selects an item in a list control.

```
<asp:SomeListControl AutoPostBack="TRUE|FALSE" runat="server"/>
```

If this property is set to TRUE the automatic post back is enabled, otherwise FALSE. Default is FALSE.

For information :[W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_listcontrol_autopostback.asp)